# How To rewrite the URL using apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the Sample URL. I want how to rewrite the URL using conf file in apache.

**http://test.local/index.cfm/a/b/** to **http://test.local/a/b/**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>  
    DocumentRoot "LocalPath"    
    ServerName alias

    Alias "/CFFileServlet" "C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\tmpCache\CFFileServlet"

    <Directory "LocalPath">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        Options MultiViews Indexes
    </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So, what it the question? You want to get know how to write pattern? Or place in configs to specify rewriting?

Comment: @TemaTre, How to write the pattern and where to place?

Comment: What  OS are you use ?

Comment: It my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify it in config.

For example in Linux OS, run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

This contains something like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Then you should specifi Rewrite Rule :

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
  RewriteEngine on
  RedirectMatch "^/index.cfm/(.*) " "/$1"
</Directory>
```

It can be another pattern, it depends on your goals and site settings.

Comment: This is not working. Its throw error like Bad request

Comment: Please provide full config listing in question.

Comment: I've added the full config